# WebKit header file confusion

Tags: c, webkit

I've downloaded and installed WebKit (webkitgtk-2.26.1) on my Ubuntu 19.04 computer for use with C/GTK+, and I have an issue with the include files.  All of the sample code I'm seeing includes the header files as `#include <webkit2/webkit2.h>`.  But there is no webkit2 folder installed with WebKit, although all the header files in ~/Utils/WebKitGtk/webkitgtk-2.26.1/Source/WebKit/UIProcess/API/gtk/webkit2 refer to 
`#include <webkit2/*.h>` as well.  I don't think I want to start editing WebKit header files, so I'm hoping someone out there has run into this and can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:
mkdir /usr/local/include/webkit2 or mkdir /usr/include/webkit2, then copy the header files into the directory.
or
configure C_INCLUDE_PATH=$C_INCLUDE_PATH:~/Utils/WebKitGtk/webkitgtk2.26.1/Source/WebKit/UIProcess/API/gtk/
you can refer to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Environment-Variables.html

Comment: Xin - I really appreciate the suggestion with the include path, and the article was certainly worth reading.  But this still doesn't cure the fact that the header files are all assumed to be in a subdirectory that doesn't exist.  Option 1 could potentially work, but again I feel like I'm doing something wrong if I have to download the software and copy it to somewhere else to make it work.

Comment: I just have to post this as a follow up for anyone else who runs into this.  Even though I was reluctant to take Xin's advice of copying the header files by hand, out of frustration I ended up doing it.  I'm here to tell you that it worked:  I copies /usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0/webkit2 to /usr/local/include/webkit2, and I also had to copy libsoap's header files the same way.  FYI, I couldn't get the files to work in their old location because I kept getting permission denied errors.